# How can I query time-series data in GridDB using SQL?

Tags: sql, syntax, time-series, timestamp, griddb

I have a lot of time-series data stored in a GridDB database, and I want to query it using SQL. However, I don't know the syntax for selecting data based on a time range.

Here's what I have so far:

```
 SELECT * FROM my_container WHERE timestamp >= '2022-01-01' AND timestamp <= '2022-01-31'
```

Comment: What is the format of your `timestamp` column ?

Comment: Does this work for you ?
    `SELECT * FROM my_container 
    WHERE timestamp > TIMESTAMP('2022-01-01') 
    AND  timestamp <= TIMESTAMP('2022-01-31');`